# elasticsearch scoring unique terms vs ngram terms

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

i've figured out how to return results on a partial word result using ngrams. but now i'd like to arrange (score or sort) my results based on the term first and then a partial term.

for example, the user searches a movie db for 'we'. i want 'we are marshall' and similar to show up at the top, and not 'north by northwest'. (the 'we' is in 'northwest').

currently this is my mapping for this title field:

```
"title": {
  "type": "string",
  "analyzer": "ngramAnalyer",
  "fields": {
     "term": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "fullTermCaseInsensitive"
     },
     "raw": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
     }
  }
}
```

i've created a multifield where ngramAnalyzer is a custom ngram, term is using a keyword tokenizer with a standard filter, and raw is not_indexed.

my query is as follows:

```
"query": {
"function_score": {
  "functions": [
    {
      "script_score": {
        "script": "_score * (1+ (1 / doc['salesrank'].value) )"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": {
             "query": "we",
              "max_expansions": 10
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      "should":{
        "term" : { 
          "title.term" : { 
            "value" : "we", 
            "boost" : 10 
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i'm basically requiring that the ngram must be matched, and the term 'we' should be matched, and if so, boost it.

this isn't working of course.

any ideas?

**edit**

to add further complexity ... how would i match first on exact title, then on a custom score?

i've taken some stabs at it, but doesn't seem to work.

for example:

```
input: 'game'
results should be ordered by exact match 'game' 
followed by a custom score based on a sales rank (integer)
so that the next results after 'game' might be something like 'hunger games'
```

Answer (score 1):

what about `bool` combination of `boosting` query, where first match about full term with 10x boost factor, and another matches against ngram term with standard boost factor?

Comment: well, i tried that but get no results because it's ONLY matching on 'we' ... and i have no titles called JUST 'we'. i'm looking to boost when it matches the single term 'we' but that it can also be a part of a larger title such as 'we are marshall'.

Comment: could you do both queries of `should` conditions?

Comment: here's what seems to work... i  re-created a multi-field mapping which consists of a whitespace mapping and an ngram mapping. the ngram matches on partial words - which i put in a 'must' clause, and the whitespace matches on a 'should' clause with a boost. the boost seems to make no difference, however... strangely enough. not gonna mark as answer b/c someone might have another idea.